# vim: conflict between mapping quote

Tags: vim

I remapped single and double quotes to the following:

```
nnoremap " ci"
nnoremap ' ci'
```

This makes editing strings easier. However, before I had defined this alias to reopen the last modified vim file. But this no more works

```
alias vil='vim -c "normal '\''0"'
```

How can I resolve this or any other mapping that works without conflicts

Comment: These mappings make it almost impossible to use registers or marks... To just save you two keystrokes on each use. Are they really worth it???

Comment: @filbranden if only I knew what registers mean and how I can use them :), once I tried to copy and paste from different apps, but it failed (before even mapping quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `normal!` to avoid mappings. See `:h :normal`